# Docker to run X applications while connected through SSH

Tags: ssh, docker, xserver

I have used these instructions for [Running Gui Apps with Docker](http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/) to create images that allow me to launch GUI based applications.

It all works flawlessly when running Docker on the same machine, but it stops working when running it on a remote host.

Locally, I can run

```
docker --rm --ti -e DISPLAY -e <X tmp> <image_name> xclock
```

And I can get `xclock` running on my host machine.

When connecting remotely to a host with `XForwarding`, I am able to run X applications that show up on my local X Server, as anyone would expect.

However if in the remote host I try to run the above docker command, it fails to connect to the `DISPLAY` (usually `localhost:10.0`)

I think the problem is that the `XForwarding` is setup on the localhost interface of the remote host.
So the docker host has no way to connect to `DISPLAY=localhost:10.0` because that localhost means the remote host, unreachable from docker itself.

Can anyone suggest an elegant way to solve this?

Regards
Alessandro

**EDIT1**:
One possible way I guess is to use `socat` to forward the remote `/tmp/.X11-unix` to the local machine. This way I would not need to use port forwarding.
It also looks like **`openssh` 6.7** will natively support unix socket forwarding.

Comment: Alessandro did you find the solution of the problem. I am facing the same problem with remote machine. On host i can run xclock but not on remote machine.....Please help!

Comment: Of course I found your question after myself having been through the same problem, figured out one solution, and filled in a full Q&A here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235040/run-x11-application-in-a-docker-container-reliably-on-a-server-connected-via-ssh  I hope that this perhaps also can solve it for you.

Answer (score 2):

When running X applications through SSH (ssh -X), you are not using the /tmp/.X11-unix socket to communicate with the X server. You are rather using a tunnel through SSH reached via "localhost:10.0".

In order to get this to work, you need to make sure the SSH server supports X connections to the external address by setting

```
X11UseLocalhost no
```

in **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**.

Then $DISPLAY inside the container should be set to the IP address of the Docker host computer on the docker interface - typically 172.17.0.1. So $DISPLAY will then be **172.17.0.1:10**

You need to add the X authentication token inside the docker container with "xauth add" (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235040/run-x-application-in-a-docker-container-reliably-on-a-server-connected-via-ssh-w#comment83459070_48235281))

If there is any firewall on the Docker host computer, you will have to open up the TCP ports related to this tunnel. Typically you will have to run something like

```
ufw allow from 172.17.0.0/16 to any port $TCPPORT proto tcp
```

if you use **ufw**.

Then it should work. I hope it helps. See also my other answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48235281/5744809 for more details.