# How to share SSH X11 forward's display with a a container?

Tags: docker

I have:

- Remote server that runs Docker container and a SSH daemon
- My own computer that can run Docker container and connect to the remote server through SSH with X11 forward

From my computer, I would like to open a GUI application located in the Docker container located in the Remote server.

- If I run the Docker container in my own computer, I can open GUI app without any problem.

  - `docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" ...`
- If I run the container in the Remote server through SSH. I get: `myapp: cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0`

I guess there is another configuration to be able to share the virtual display created by the SSH connection to the container.

I am not running any SSH server in the Docker container and I don't want to.

#### How can I share the SSH X11 forward display with a Docker container?

- If possible with a transparent way, no matter I run the container in local or remotely through SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following on the host:

```
sudo xhost +local:root
```

Comment: Actually I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235040/run-x-application-in-a-docker-container-reliably-on-a-server-connected-via-ssh-w/48235281#48235281